# Powershell EnableFILESTREAM does not effect

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
$strComputer = "."
$strInstanceName = "SQLSERVER2008"
$wmi=Get-WmiObject -computerName $strComputer -namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 -class FILESTREAMSettings -filter "InstanceName='SQLSERVER2008'"
Write-Output $wmi.AccessLevel
$wmi.EnableFILESTREAM(2, "SQLSERVER2008") 
$wmi=Get-WmiObject -computerName $strComputer -namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 -class FILESTREAMSettings -filter "InstanceName='SQLSERVER2008'"
Write-Output $wmi.AccessLevel
```

I run this script but it does not effect.
The $wmi.AccessLevel before and after running $wmi.EnableFILESTREAM(1, "SQLSERVER2008") is still 0

Comment: read here myabe can help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/06/09/enabling-filestream-post-sql2008-setup-a-known-issue-in-sql-config-manager.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to call this:

```
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
RECONFIGURE
```

from PowerShell. The important part being "reconfigure".

```
$ServerInstance = "SQLSERVER2008"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerInstance;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;"

$Command = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$Command.CommandText = "EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2; RECONFIGURE"

$sqlConnection.Open()
$Command.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
$sqlConnection.Close()
```